# CSS center images by only changing image properties

Tags: html, css, image

I have automatically generated HTML (almost impossible to change it because it is generated by a third party library) that can generate this kind of HTML

```
<p>
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
</p>
```

It produces something like this screenshot:

[image: Images that need to be horizontally centered]

I would like to be able to center the 2 image horizontally (here there are 2 but we can I have 1 or more).

Added: Full html

```
<div class="innercontent" data-slide-fit="fit" style="font-size: 32px;"><h1>Images</h1>
<ul>
<li>Images can be local or from Internet. It is recommended to use local images for better performances.</li>
</ul>
<p><img src="img/photos-background.jpg" alt="" style="max-height: 267.9692951849267px;">
<img src="img/photos-background.jpg" alt="" style="max-height: 267.9692951849267px;"></p>
<ul>
<li>They are streched or resized in order to occupy available space while giving room for other elements.</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the text is also inside the `p`?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the html code when on inspect element or view source? I can't seem to replicate the markup. I tried it with the snippet on the answers but the <img> tags are not rendered inside the <p> tag when checking inspect element and view source.

Comment: I've added the full html

Answer (score 0):

If we consisder the fact that the images will have the same width, you can approximate this using translate and margin. It's an approximation because there is the tiny space between the images

```html
<p>
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/150/100" style="margin-left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%)">
</p>

<p>
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/150/100" style="margin-left:50%;transform:translateX(-100%)">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/150/100" style="transform:translateX(-100%)" >
</p>

<p>
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/150/100" style="margin-left:50%;transform:translateX(-150%)">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/150/100" style="transform:translateX(-150%)" >
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/150/100" style="transform:translateX(-150%)" >
</p>
```

Or like below to avoid the wrapping.

```html
<p>
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/150/100" style="margin-left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);">
</p>

<p>
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/150/100" style="margin-left:50%;transform:translateX(-100%);margin-right:-150px;">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/150/100"  >
</p>

<p>
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/150/100" style="margin-left:50%;transform:translateX(-150%);margin-right:-225px;">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/150/100"  >
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/150/100" >
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, images can have different dimensions (there are chopped by the user)

Answer (score 0):

You can add one class to p tag parent:

p.image-center{display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}

Comment: *center images by only changing image properties*